# Adding Additional Parameters to a link based on form Input

Tags: html, forms, parameters, input, param

I am trying to add whatever is given as input for the input tags with id "tid" and "split_fraction" as additional paramaters on my link. How would I  do this?

```
<span>Id:</span><input id="tid" size =  "6">
<span>Split fraction</span><input id="split_fraction" size = "6">  
<a href=/test?Rule_Type=tid&mid=3&cid=4" >Add</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need to reformat your form.

```
<form method="GET" action="/test">
    <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="4">
    <label for="tid">Id:</label><input id="tid" name="tid" maxlength="6">
    <label for="split_fraction">Split Fraction:</label><input id="split_fraction" name="split_fraction" maxlength="6">

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

### What I changed

- I changed your `<span>`s to `<label>`s which better describe the
  labels for your inputs, also using GET
- I've changed the parameters already existing in the URL to hidden inputs.
- I've added names to the inputs so that they will occur in the URL parsing.
- I've changed the submit link to a submit `<button>` which better describes what you want to do. You may also use `<input type="submit">`

Comment: Thanks! My only question is how do I control where the submit button takes the user, what is the link?

Comment: That one is found in the `<form>` element `action=` attribute, it will redirect to `/test`, those extra parameters (mid and cid) are now in hidden inputs and will be included in the form.

Comment: @Spencer if my answer is correct, please upvote (if you haven't already) and accept it as correct. Thanks :)

Comment: I did up-vote it. I was waiting to implement before accepting. I just implemented and it worked.